# Add nested column to BigQuery table, joining on value of another nested column in standard SQL

Tags: sql, join, nested, google-bigquery

I have a reasonably complex dataset being pulled into BigQuery table via an Airflow DAG which cannot easily be adjusted.

This job pulls data into a table with this format:

```
| Line_item_id | Device         |
|--------------|----------------|
| 123          | 202; 5; 100    |
| 124          | 100; 2         |
| 135          | 504; 202; 2    |
```

At the moment, I am using this query (written in standard SQL within the BQ Web UI) to split the device ids into individual nested rows:

```
SELECT 
  Line_item_id,
  ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT(SPLIT(RTRIM(Device,';'),'; '))) as Device,
```

Output:

```
| Line_item_id | Device |
|--------------|--------|
| 123          | 202    |
|              | 203    |
|              | 504    |
| 124          | 102    |
|              | 2      |
| 135          | 102    |
```

The difficulty I am facing is I have a separate match table containing the device ids and their corresponding names. I need to add the device names to the above table, as nested values next to their corresponding ids.

The match table looks something like this (with many more rows):

```
| Device_id | Device_name |
|-----------|-------------|
| 202       | Smartphone  |
| 203       | AppleTV     |
| 504       | Laptop      |
```

The ideal output I am looking for would be:

```
| Line_item_id | Device_id | Device_name |
|--------------|-----------|-------------|
| 123          | 202       | Android     |
|              | 203       | AppleTV     |
|              | 504       | Laptop      |
| 124          | 102       | iphone      |
|              | 2         | Unknown     |
| 135          | 102       | iphone      |
```

If anybody knows how to achieve this I would be grateful for help.

EDIT:

Gordon's solution works perfectly, but in addition to this, if anybody wants to re-nest the data afterwards (so you effectively end up with the same table and additional nested rows), this was the query I finally ended up with:

```
select t.line_item_id, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(d as id, ot.name as name)) as device
from first_table t cross join
     unnest(split(Device, '; ')) d join
     match_table ot
     on ot.id  = d
GROUP BY line_item_id
```

Comment: . . It is unclear to me where `203` and `6` went for `124`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the parsing logic to the `from` clause and then `join` in what you want:

```
select *
from (select 124 as line_item_id, '203; 100; 6; 2' as device) t cross join
     unnest(split(device, '; ')) d join
     other_table ot
     on ot.device = d;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, could you adjust this to work if both tables have names? The select statement within the from clause you have used doesn't work for me as I am pulling the original line_item_id and device info in from a table within the query too, not writing those in from scratch

Comment: @DarceyBM . . . Just replace the subquery before `t` with whatever table you are using.

Comment: Thanks! There are further columns I haven't included here for simplicity but this is easy to adjust.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL.   No GROUP BY required ...

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(Device), 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT Device_id AS id, Device_name AS name
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(REPLACE(Device, ' ', ''), ';')) Device_id WITH OFFSET
    JOIN `project.dataset.devices` 
    USING(Device_id)
    ORDER BY OFFSET
  ) Device
FROM `project.dataset.items`
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - result is

[image]

FYI: I used below data to test

```
WITH `project.dataset.items` AS (
  SELECT 123 Line_item_id, '202; 5; 100' Device UNION ALL
  SELECT 124, '100; 2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 135, '504; 202; 2' 
), `project.dataset.devices` AS (
  SELECT '202' Device_id, 'Smartphone' Device_name UNION ALL
  SELECT '203', 'AppleTV' UNION ALL
  SELECT '504', 'Laptop' UNION ALL
  SELECT '5', 'abc' UNION ALL
  SELECT '100', 'xyz' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2', 'zzz'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to `UNNEST` the contents of your devices array, and then to roll it back up after joining with the `devices` metatable:

```
select 
   line_item_id, 
   array_agg(struct(device_id as device_id, device_name as device_name)) as devices 
from (
   select 
      d.line_item_id, 
      device_id, 
      n.device_name 
   from `mydataset.basetable` d, unnest(d.device_ids) as device_id
   left join `mydataset.devices_table` n on n.device_id = device_id
)
group by line_item_id
```

Hope this helps.